# How to Disable Mobile View in Magento and Display the Desktop screen

Tags: magento, mobile, view, themes

I was Using Venus theme on Magento,

When i am trying to load my site on mobile , the content is been displayed in irregular format.  i want to disable responsive layout so that the same desktop style should be displayed on Mobile.

Can some One help in finding out this.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Now at present its running on a local host . ... !!!! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is some difficult task for developer, check CSS of remove all CSS for using mobile view. I think You should try to make correct responsive view. You can find by media screen size.